# Is there a way to auto delete indendations from code so you can more easily use the code block?

Tags: support, feature-request, code-formatting

I have issues submitting my code when there are indentations in it because the code sample button doesn't detect the code unless it has exactly 4 spaces before it. Is there a quicker way to handle this instead of just manually clicking and deleting every indentation I see? This can take 10 minutes on long code.

Thank you!

Comment: Select the code block, then Ctrl-K.  There is also gobs of help on the edit toolbar - click the `?`

Comment: I might be wrong, but isnt this asking how to *remove* the extra indentations you often have when copying code from an IDE, rather than how to *add* them?

Comment: As an aside, if it's taking you 10 minutes to indent/outdent your code, you may be including too much code. Depends on how fast you delete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a curly brace button in the top of the editor that if you highlight your code and press it it will indent the selection for you.

[image]

You can also highlight your code and use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

You can go [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see the help page for using the editor.

Comment: Ahh, for some reason the first time I tried this it just didn't work, but it's working now! This was a silly question then on my part! Sorry. I can't even accept your answer because I only have 13 reputation

Comment: @JGoldz75 No problem.  Everyone can use some [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) now and again.  Besides I think you can accept an answer at any reputation it just makes you wait so long before you can accept it.

Comment: Ahh I can accept an answer it looks like, just cannot upvote! Answer accepted.